# Getting cell-backgroundcolor in Excel with Open XML 2.0

Tags: c#, excel, .net-4.0, openxml-sdk

I am trying to get the backgroundcolor of a cell in a excel-spreadsheet. I am using Open XML 2.0 SDK and I am able to open the *.xlsx-file and to get cell-values for example. My code for getting the Background-Color is the following:

```
   public BackgroundColor GetCellBackColor(Cell theCell, SpreadsheetDocument document)
    {
        BackgroundColor backGroundColor = null;
        WorkbookStylesPart styles = SpreadsheetReader.GetWorkbookStyles(document);
        int cellStyleIndex = (int)theCell.StyleIndex.Value;
        CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)styles.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements[cellStyleIndex];
        Fill fill = (Fill)styles.Stylesheet.Fills.ChildElements[(int)cellFormat.FillId.Value];
        backGroundColor = fill.PatternFill.BackgroundColor;

        return backGroundColor;
    }
```

My problem here is, that `PatternFill.BackgroundColor` returns just a natural number, I think it's the id of the style. My problem is, that the line of code

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color c = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color)styles.Stylesheet.Colors.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(backGroundColor.InnerText)];
```

returns with an error, because `Stylesheet.Colors` is `null`... ...maybe it's because I used a "built in" color in excel - not an self-defined color?!

Any ideas how I could "calculate" the real color-number from the "backGroundColor-Value"?

Comment: The class SpreadsheetReader does not exists in OpenXML 2.5

Comment: @Elmue In order to use SpreadsheetReader, you need to also install [DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Extensions/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fill pattern of a cell in an excel spreadsheet is
composed of two colors: The background color and the foreground color.
The term foreground color is a little bit misleading here. It is not the
color of the font but the foreground color of the pattern fill.

For example if you fill the background of a cell with a solid color
the `ForegroundColor` property of the releated `PatternFill` object of the cell
is set to the choosen solid color value where as The `BackgroundColor` object
is set to the system foreground color. The `PatternType` property of the
`PatternFill` object is set to `PatternValues.Solid`.

So, to get the color value of your cell background (solid fill), you have to analyze the
the `ForegroundColor` property of the releated `PatternFill` object. You have to
determine the "type of color" the instance represents:

1. An automatic color and system dependent color
2. An indexed color.
3. An ARGB color (alpha, red, green and blue)
4. A theme based color.
5. A tint value applied to the color.

For more information about the different "color types" see the following
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.foregroundcolor.aspx).

Please note that the meaning of the `InnerText` property of the `ForegroundColor` and `BackgroundColor`
class depends on the color type. For example in case of a theme based color the `InnerText` property
is set to the index into the `ColorScheme` collection.

The following example prints all background color information for all cells in a spreadsheet document:

```
public static PatternFill GetCellPatternFill(Cell theCell, SpreadsheetDocument document)
{ 
  WorkbookStylesPart styles = SpreadsheetReader.GetWorkbookStyles(document);

  int cellStyleIndex;
  if (theCell.StyleIndex == null) // I think (from testing) if the StyleIndex is null
  {                               // then this means use cell style index 0.
    cellStyleIndex = 0;           // However I did not found it in the open xml 
  }                               // specification.
  else
  {
    cellStyleIndex = (int)theCell.StyleIndex.Value;
  }      

  CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)styles.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements[cellStyleIndex];

  Fill fill = (Fill)styles.Stylesheet.Fills.ChildElements[(int)cellFormat.FillId.Value];
  return fill.PatternFill;  
}

private static void PrintColorType(SpreadsheetDocument sd, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.ColorType ct)
{
  if (ct.Auto != null)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("System auto color");
  }

  if (ct.Rgb != null)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("RGB value -> {0}", ct.Rgb.Value);
  }

  if (ct.Indexed != null)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Indexed color -> {0}", ct.Indexed.Value);

    //IndexedColors ic = (IndexedColors)styles.Stylesheet.Colors.IndexedColors.ChildElements[(int)bgc.Indexed.Value];         
  }

  if (ct.Theme != null)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Theme -> {0}", ct.Theme.Value);

    Color2Type c2t = (Color2Type)sd.WorkbookPart.ThemePart.Theme.ThemeElements.ColorScheme.ChildElements[(int)ct.Theme.Value];

    Console.Out.WriteLine("RGB color model hex -> {0}", c2t.RgbColorModelHex.Val);
  }

  if (ct.Tint != null)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Tint value -> {0}", ct.Tint.Value);
  }
}

static void ReadAllBackgroundColors()
{
  using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("c:\\temp\\bgcolor.xlsx", false))
  {
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    foreach(WorksheetPart worksheetPart in workbookPart.WorksheetParts)
    {
      SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

      foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
      {
        foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
        {            
          Console.Out.WriteLine("----------------");
          PatternFill pf = GetCellPatternFill(c, spreadsheetDocument);        

          Console.Out.WriteLine("Pattern fill type -> {0}", pf.PatternType.Value);

          if (pf.PatternType == PatternValues.None)
          {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("No fill color specified");
            continue;
          }

          Console.Out.WriteLine("Summary foreground color:");
          PrintColorType(spreadsheetDocument, pf.ForegroundColor);
          Console.Out.WriteLine("Summary background color:");
          PrintColorType(spreadsheetDocument, pf.BackgroundColor);                          
        }
      }     
    }
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
  ReadAllBackgroundColors();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Just one point to add: If I don't change the style of a cell, the line ` int cellStyleIndex = (int)theCell.StyleIndex.Value;` causes a null-exception. How can I know for sure, that it is actually the default-style and "what" style (color etc.) this is? Thx in advance!

Comment: @chiffre: I think (I did some testing) if StyleIndex is null you have to use cell style index 0. However I did not found a note about it in the open xml specification.

Comment: Thanks for that information. There is really the need for a good and complete wrapper - where you can simply call "cell.GetColor" etc.. (and that actually works ;) )

Comment: Thanks for this thorough explanation, but I find that you can't reliably get colors from `ThemeElements.ColorScheme` using `ColorType.Theme` as an index: Indexes 0 and 1 (usually black/white) have swapped places, and also indexes 2 and 3. These are the theme's "Dark1"/"Light1"/"Dark2"/"Light2" colors. Can we count on these indexes always being swapped, or do we need to find the theme colors some other way?

Comment: The same code works for the font attributes as well. Thanks for helping. For the record: Extract the font id and get the font (type Font) from the Fonts property.

Comment: That's why I don't like OpenXML. It is too awkward! How is it possible that Microsoft did not implement a function for such a basic task as getting the color of a cell?

Comment: In order to use SpreadsheetReader, you need to also install [DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Extensions/). I found this out from this other question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584870/openxml-spreadsheetreader-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

I would suggest an edit, but [the edit queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full).

Answer (score 1):

Well I had a similiar use case in which I need to test which RGB Color is applied as background Color to Cell. Just Appending to code from your function,

```
backGroundColor = fill.PatternFill.BackgroundColor.Rgb.Value;
return backgroundColor;
```

This would return the Rgb Color Value used in the background of cell.

Answer (score 0):

[Hans's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10789189/5522453) answer is great! I wanted to add to it since I had to parse a gradient fill for some of the columns. Here is my solution:

I just wanted to get the rgb string, if your requirement is different you will have to change the return type accordingly.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCellFillColors(string sheetName,
     string addressName, WorkbookPart wbPart)
    {
        WorkbookStylesPart styles = wbPart.WorkbookStylesPart;

        Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().
          Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

        // Throw an exception if there is no sheet.
        if (theSheet == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("sheetName");
        }

        // Retrieve a reference to the worksheet part.
        WorksheetPart wsPart =
            (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));

        // Use its Worksheet property to get a reference to the cell 
        // whose address matches the address you supplied.
        Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
          Where(c => c.CellReference == addressName).FirstOrDefault();

        int cellStyleIndex;
        if (theCell.StyleIndex == null) // I think (from testing) if the StyleIndex is null
        {                               // then this means use cell style index 0.
            cellStyleIndex = 0;           // However I did not found it in the open xml 
        }                               // specification.
        else
        {
            cellStyleIndex = (int)theCell.StyleIndex.Value;
        }

        CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)styles.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements[cellStyleIndex];

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill fill = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Fill)styles.Stylesheet.Fills.ChildElements[(int)cellFormat.FillId.Value];

        if (fill.PatternFill != null)
        {
            return fill.PatternFill?.BackgroundColor?.Rgb?.ToString() != null ?
            new List<string>()
            {
                fill.PatternFill?.BackgroundColor?.Rgb?.ToString()
            } : new List<string>();
        }

        if (fill.GradientFill != null)
        {
            var colors = fill.GradientFill.ChildElements.Select(e => (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.GradientStop)e);
            return colors?.Select(c => c?.Color.Rgb?.ToString());

        }

        return null;
    }
```