# OpenXML - SpreadsheetReader does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openxml

So I was trying to replicate this answer [Getting cell-backgroundcolor in Excel with Open XML 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756206/getting-cell-backgroundcolor-in-excel-with-open-xml-2-0)

but VS is complaining about `SpreadsheetReader` not existing in the current context. I can't `ctrl+.` resolve the issue.

Here is the (almost working) code:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

public static DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PatternFill GetCellPatternFill(Cell theCell, SpreadsheetDocument document)
{
    WorkbookStylesPart styles = SpreadsheetReader.GetWorkbookStyles(document);

    int cellStyleIndex;
    if (theCell.StyleIndex == null) // I think (from testing) if the StyleIndex is null
    {                               // then this means use cell style index 0.
        cellStyleIndex = 0;           // However I did not found it in the open xml 
    }                               // specification.
    else
    {
        cellStyleIndex = (int)theCell.StyleIndex.Value;
    }

    CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)styles.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements[cellStyleIndex];

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Fill fill = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Fill)styles.Stylesheet.Fills.ChildElements[(int)cellFormat.FillId.Value];
    return fill.PatternFill;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Extensions.
This extension can be downloaded from   https://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/48673

Cheers Karel Groos

Answer (score 3):

I by passed simpleOOXML by using

```
WorkbookStylesPart styles = document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;
```

instead of

```
WorkbookStylesPart styles = SpreadsheetReader.GetWorkbookStyles(document);
```