# How to get Cell background color using OpenXML SDK in c#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, openxml-sdk, vba

I want to get cell background color using OpenXML SDK in c#. Things I have done yet:

```
WorkbookStylesPart styles = document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;
Stylesheet stylesheet = styles.Stylesheet;
CellFormats cellformats = stylesheet.CellFormats;
//Fonts fonts = stylesheet.Fonts;

CellFormat f = (CellFormat)cellformats.ElementAt((int)cell.StyleIndex.Value);
Fill fill = (Fill)styles.Stylesheet.Fills.ChildElements[(int)f.FillId.Value];
fill.PatternFill.BackgroundColor = ???
```

what to put in RHS in above statement?

Comment: do you want to get the background color or set it?

Comment: then I think your question mark has to be in the LHS

Comment: Do u know how to set it?

Comment: for you to set the color into the PatternFill Class, You could try to get it from Color.FromArgb Method from the System.Drawing Namespace

Comment: are you still trying to solve this?  Would getting the background color of any cell in an excel worksheet be acceptable?

Comment: You find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756206/getting-cell-backgroundcolor-in-excel-with-open-xml-2-0